# selected=selected based on value in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently working on my own CMS where a user can add and update his projects.
Adding them works like a charm, and the update is working aswell, but when i click on a project (it gets all info based on a `$_GET['id']`) the categorie value is always the first option in my select element.

I know this can be achieved by adding `selected="selected"` to the option element, but I want to have this working with values from the database and that's where I am getting confused.

I'd like to have this part dynamic:

```
<select  name="categorie">
   <option value="cv">CV / Boiler</option>
   <option value="onderhoudrenovatie">Onderhoud & Renovatie</option>
   <option value="sanitair">Sanitair</option>
</select>
```

The option values are already written to the database in the field 'categorie' in the table 'projecten' when adding them.

Does anyone have a solution?
Thank you!

Comment: First you have to tell us what you're pulling from the database in order to help and know what to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the value and assign to a variable. Then, with basic PHP you can select printing "selected" or not depending on the value.

For example something like this:

```
<?php $data=$_GET['id']; ?>

<select  name="categorie">
 <option value="cv" <?php if ($data=="cv") print "selected"; ?>>CV / Boiler</option>
 <option value="onderhoudrenovatie" <?php if ($data=="onderhoudrenovatie") print "selected"; ?>>Onderhoud & Renovatie</option>
 <option value="sanitair" <?php if ($data=="sanitair") print "selected"; ?>>Sanitair</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer is troublesome and wrong. Single `=` is used to assign, `==` is used to compare.

Comment: I know. It was my first fast answer, now I am improving the answer.

Comment: Well you should consider giving a logical answer for the first time too.

Comment: It was. It is good wait till the answer is complete, as you could see is was "under construction" :)

Comment: fedorqui, no need to defend yourself!
Your solution worked like a charm =)
I know the differences between the = and the == so that was no problem at all.

Comment: PS: The solution was so easy and right in front of my eyes! Funny i didn't come up with it after a good 3 years of experience with php/mysql

Comment: Haha no problem @MichaelKoelewijn, now you will for sure remember it! :) And also mark the question as "answered" if it is done. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks fedorqui! I've accepted your answer as the one that helped me (:

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
$categories = array() ; //Fill your array with data from your database ;
$selectedId = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : null ;

foreach ($categories as $cat){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $cat['name'] ;?>" <?php echo (!empty($selectedId) &&  $cat['id'] == $selectedId) ? "selected" : "") ; ?> >
      <?php echo $cat['name'] ; ?>
    </option>

 <?php
}
```